# Has the age at which we teach Mathematics changed over the last two centuries?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, soft-question, education

My experience of learning Advanced Trigonometry and Calculus is that it was done to 17 and 18 year olds (School Curriculum in Australia). I assumed that it was similar in the UK, US and Europe.

In [the book Master and Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_and_Commander) we see the main character Jack Albury tell of his childhood learning mathematics. It appears he learned Cotangents and Integration at age 12.

Now I'm not saying this is not possible, and that there are probably 12-year-olds out there with untapped potential. I'm trying to understand what Mathematics would have been taught at this point in time (to sailors for navigation). Is it likely that they learned a rote formula for navigation, and understanding the stresses on a ship, or would they have learned first-principles?

Now this novel is set in the period of English History [1800-1815] and is [generally regarded](http://www.nytimes.com/library/books/010700obit-obrian.html) to be [meticulously researched](http://www.smh.com.au/articles/2003/11/28/1069825977816.html) [historical fiction](http://www.nytimes.com/books/98/10/18/specials/obrian-comesin.html).

My question is: **Has the age at which we teach Mathematics changed over the last two centuries?**

Comment: Hello, I added the tag "soft-question" so that this nice question can more likely be prevented from being closed or anything else we do not want to see. :)

Comment: I am no expert, but I feel like an increasingly common facet of modern education (at least in America and the UK) is an increasing element of standardization. I have no clue if this existed in the 1800's, but I doubt it. It seems likely that in that period it was more acceptable to start learning at various ages and learn at different rates than it was today. I'll let someone more knowledgeable of the history answer the question  properly though.

Comment: i think that now we learn these things much more earlier than we used to do

Comment: The emergence of personal computers and internet may play a non-negligible role; knowledge disseminated much more faster than ever for both scholars and students. Another reason I think about is that, because some mathematics have finally been understood thoroughly so that the great masters can make those math. easy such that they can be "explained" to the first person one meets on the street.

Comment: @hawkeye It's true that many fields have their students study certain topics much later (and sometimes much longer) than their ancestors did. Some classic scientists, physicians, and lawyers of high acclaim were in their late teens and early twenties during their practice. Consider also that there has been a significant increase in the amount of things we know about the world between now and then. I'd say, though, that this point has a lot more to do with university studies than secondary schools. I feel that the secondary school system is very flawed in their methodology of teaching maths.

Comment: The failure of the education movement in the 1960s to 'modernise' the maths taught in schools (SMP/Nuffield in the UK, New Maths in the US, the Lichnerowicz Commission in France) suggests that you need quite a bit of time between the discovery of new mathematics and it's introduction into schools. Interestingly the topics that stayed from SMP (like co-ordinate geometry) are the more established ones. I'm surprised that calculus hadn't entered the curriculum earlier as the method of exhaustion has been around for a long time.

Comment: What you are still taught around age 12 or earlier these days is basic physics, for which Calculus was invented and applied to understand better. So you get to learn acceleration and velocity without learning how it was these things came to be understood until much later.

Answer (score 1):

Well It depends on what you think about mathematics. Generally, Through history we all learn mathematics from a very young age because We learn counting.

Now Isaac newton didn't learn calculus in University because he is the one who came up with calculus in the first place and therefore, Nowadays, The mathematical curriculum for university involves way more advanced mathematics compared to 100 years back. Now we have graph theory , combinatorics , Modern Algebra , Number theory and topology. This is way more math than they did 100 years ago, I would say even Einstein didn't do a lot of math compared to People doing research now.

In the future, I think people will learn more about modular arithmetic and number theory earlier than they do nowadays.